# Walk Through for Autodesk

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

My Team has created a walk through in their Revit software as its been shown in this video [here][1]. We are looking for a way to render this walk through in Forge Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #1: I'm afraid the walkthrough information is *not* extracted by the Model Derivative service, so it will not be available automatically in Forge Viewer.

Regarding #2: This is more a question for the [Revit API forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160) but I believe that it should be possible to extract the walkthrough from your Revit model programmatically. And if it is possible, you could even automate this process by running your Revit plugin in the [Forge Design Automation service](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3).

Regarding #3 and #4: If you are able to extract the walkthrough camera data, let's say into a JSON file, you can definitely implement a similar walkthrough in Forge Viewer, for example, using the [viewer.navigation.setView](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/#setview-position-target) method, or using something like `viewer.navigation.setRequestTransition(state, pos, coi, fov, reorient, pivot)`. This is the docs for the individual arguments:

```js
/**
 * Issue a request to transition the current cameras view to that specified by the parameters.
 *  @param {boolean} state - value of the request. Set to true in order to request the change of view.
 *  @param {THREE.Vector3} pos - the new camera position in world space
 *  @param {THREE.Vector3} coi - the point in world space that the camera should look towards.
 *  @param {number} fov - vertical field of view in degrees
 *  @param {boolean} reorient - set to true to recalculate up vector
 *  @param {THREE.Vector3} pivot - the new pivot point
 */
```

Comment: is it possible to extract data of Path Of Travel because I can see the path polygons on my viewer but I am not able to find the process of accessing that data, can you provide your thoughts on that ?

Comment: Hi Petr. Is there any built-in end user functionality in the Forge viewer to generate and store a walkthrough path for other viewer users to easily replay?

Comment: Hi guys, the SVF format does not support storing any "walkthrough" paths. You would have to define those separately, and then interpret path yourself by interpolating the camera between individual waypoints.

Comment: Ronak, if there is already some kind of a polyline in your SVF file, you could try and access it using the standard `FragmentList` approach (see https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer, and search for `getVizmesh`).